what do the green and white colors mean in VScode when I import modules?
I get different colors in VSCode when I write code to import my own modules. They are in different folder at the same level. What does green and white mean? They both work fine.

Here is the folder structure:

It is NOT the __init __.py file, removing it changes nothing.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Your directory tree could probably be better expressed as text in a code block using the tree command.

It mostly depends on the theme you are using in your VSCode. For example, some themes color code the used and unused imports differently. It seems that you've imported, for example, init_db, but haven't used anywhere down in the code and opposite for gather_all and others (i.e.: used somewhere down in the code) ¯\(ツ)/¯. But still, it depends on the theme and have (really!) no special meaning.

@Anerdw It is absolutely fine to upload an image if the information presented is graphical. Here the code itself was secondary, the actual highlighting was presented.

@KlausD I was talking about the file tree, not the code.

@Anerdw Then you should have made that clearer as "code/data/error". Also I don't agree that the tree has to be textual. The main reasons for posting code as text is to make it copyable / editable which is rarely required to directory trees.

@KlausD The link was boilerplate, but I did link to the tree command. And there are many reasons why images should generally be avoided besides copy-paste, which are listed out in the "don't use images" meta post.
